# Section of the spinor bundle over $S^{1}$ that extend to sections of the spinor bundle over $D^{2}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, vector-bundles, spin-geometry, conformal-field-theory, spinor

Let $\mathbb{S} \rightarrow S^{1}$ be the spinor bundle associated to the connected double cover $\text{Spin}(S^{1}) \rightarrow S^{1}$. Let $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow D^{2}$ be the spinor bundle associated to the bundle $\text{Spin}(D^{2})$. We may view $\text{Spin}(S^{1})$ as sitting in $\text{Spin}(D^{2})$, (as discussed in for example [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114660/spin-structures-on-s1-and-spin-cobordism)). This means that there is a an induced map $\mathbb{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$, and thus if we have a section $f: S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}$ we may ask if there is a section $F: D^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ with the property that $F|_{S^{1}} = f$.

> Are there simple conditions on a section $f: S^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}$ that guarantee that $f$ extends to a *holomorphic* section $F: D^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$.

The space of sections, $\Gamma(S^{1}, \mathbb{S})$, may be identified with the space of anti-periodic functions on the circle. We may write down an explicit basis
\begin{equation}
 \eta_{n}(t) = e^{i(n+1/2)t}, \quad (t \in [0,2\pi], n \in \mathbb{Z}).
\end{equation}
A guess would be that functions that are linear combinations of $\eta_{n}$ with $n \geqslant 0$ extend to holomorphic sections $\Gamma(D^{2}, \mathbb{D})$, but I'm not sure how to continue from there.

As an aside, the context that I'm trying to understand this in are [these lecture notes](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/Teaching/CFT-2014.pdf) on conformal nets by André Henriques.